# How many actual bytes of memory node.js Buffer uses internally to store 1 logical byte of data?

Tags: node.js, memory-efficient

Node.js documentations states that:

> A Buffer is similar to an array of integers but corresponds to a raw memory allocation outside the V8 heap.

Am I right that all integers are represented as 64-bit floats internally in javascript?

Does it mean that storing 1 byte in Node.js Buffer actually takes 8 bytes of memory?

Thanks

Comment: Why would integers be stored as floating-point numbers? Did you read that somewhere, or is it just a guess?

Comment: @Jongware I assume that is an extrapolation from all numbers in JS being floating-point.

Comment: Buffers are arrays of bytes, so they will store just as many bytes as you would expect.

Comment: Interesting -- [this has been so since the very first version](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.5) (link to ECMAScript 5.1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buffers are simply an array of bytes, so the length of the buffer is essentially the number of bytes that the Buffer will occupy.

For instance, the [new Buffer(size)](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_new_buffer_size) constructor is documented as `"Allocates a new buffer of size octets."` Here `octets` clearly identifies the cells as single-byte values. Similarly [`buf[index]`](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_index) states `"Get and set the octet at index. The values refer to individual bytes, so the legal range is between 0x00 and 0xFF hex or 0 and 255."`.

While a buffer is absolutely an array of bytes, you may interact with it as integers or other types using the [buf.read*](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_readuint32le_offset_noassert) class of functions available on the buffer object. Each of these has a specific number of bytes that are affected by the operations.

For more specifics on the internals, Node just passes the length through to [`smalloc`](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/cfcb1de130867197cbc9c6012b7e84e08e53d032/src/node_buffer.cc#L161) which just uses [`malloc`](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/cfcb1de130867197cbc9c6012b7e84e08e53d032/src/smalloc.cc#L332) as you'd expect to allocate the specified number of bytes.

Comment: There is likely to be a small (constant) amount of per-object overhead as well.

Comment: @Kevin Yup, that's what I was trying to get across with the `essentially`.

Comment: @loganfsmyth, Could you please give a link to a source? Thanks

Comment: @loganfsmyth I'm still not sure. Documentation is allowed to describe things how we should think about them and not how they are actually implemented. My question was about the actual implementation of Buffer, i.e. how many actual bytes in memory it occupies for one 'octet slot'. Could you please provide a link to the sources to verify that documentation speaks about the actual implementation? Thanks

Comment: @AlexYursha Updated. If you are looking for such specifics, in the future, please make that clearer in your original question.